# Understanding u-substitution theorem for integration when "u" is non-linear

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Integrating

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt[4]{2x-1}}$$

by using the substitution $2x-1=u^4$ (non-linear u) yields

$$\int \frac{2u^3}{u^2-u}du$$

How are these steps justified by the substitution theorem?

The substitution theorem states that if $u=\varphi(x)$, $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, $\varphi(x)$ differentiable, then

$$\int f(\varphi(x))\varphi '(x)dx=\int f(u)du$$

Directly applying it to introductory problem would result in

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d(u^4)}{u^2-u}$$ I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: What is $d(u^4)$? Try to compute it

Comment: Thank you for your input! I know of $d(u^4)$ only as the notation saying we're differentiating by the variable $u^4$. I don't know how to do any computations with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the rules of differential calculus assert that $\;\mathrm d(u^4)=4u^3\,\mathrm du$, and differentiating the relation $2x-1=u^4$ yields $\;2\mathrm d x=4u^3\,\mathrm d u$, so we have to replace in the integral $\,\mathrm dx$ with $2u^3\,\mathrm du$, and the integral becomes indeed
$$\int \frac{2u^3}{u^2-u}\,\mathrm du=\int \frac{2u^2}{u-1}\,\mathrm du.$$
Thus the integral has become the integral of a rational function. As the degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator, one has first to perform the euclidean division:
$$2u^2=(2u+2)(u-1)
+2\implies \frac{2u^2}{u-1}=2(u+1)+\frac 2{u-1}.$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Ah, I guess my question is then "why is $d(u^4)=4u^3du$ "which is a different topic. I know how to calculate the integral, but I was wondering about the fundamentals. I get that the derivative of $u^4$ is $4u^3$ but I am uncomfortable with treating differentiation "as a fraction" and dealing with $du$ as a single element, not as a part of something like $\frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: By definition, the differential of a (single variable) function is the derivative of this function, times the differential of the variable, which is a symbol representing a small increment of the variable. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt[4]{2x-1}}\,dx$$

Letting $2x-1 = u^4$ means that $(2x-1)' = (u^4)' \iff \color{blue}{2\,dx = 4u^3\,du}$.

Hence you have that $$\frac 12\int \frac {\color{blue}{2dx}}{\sqrt{2x-1}- \sqrt[4]{2x-1}} = \frac 12\int \frac {\color{blue}{4u^3\,du}}{u^2 - u} = 2 \int \frac{u^2}{u-1}\,du$$

$$= \int \left(2(u+1)+\frac 2{u-1}\right)\,du$$

$$= u^2 + 2u + 2\ln|u-1| + C = u^2 + 2u+ \ln(u-1)^2+C.$$

Now, remember that $u = \sqrt[4]{2x-1}$.

Comment: This does not show how the substitution theorem is applied to yield that result. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: Yes, in fact, it does show that.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\frac{d}{du}u^4=4u^3$. If we abuse notation somewhat, we get that $\frac{d(u^4)}{du}=4u^3$, thus $d(u^4)=4u^3{du}$. Combining the $\frac12$ in the front with the $4u^3$ give $2u^3$.